# Xampp is too small and I can't resize

Tags: 22.04, xampp

I just installed Ubuntu and trying to use xampp on it, but the GUI wizard of xampp is too small and I can't resize it. Does anyone have this kind of problem?

[image: here]

Comment: It is the actual size it needs to be. There is nothing more than this. Wait for the installer to complete and then click finish. " But the GUI wizard of xampp is too small " it is not a "gui wizard" It is the installer.

Comment: I have installed it already. It is still small compared to other images on the internet. Please see the image [link](https://imgur.com/Fra4zLK)